# Why the blank lines in this console output?

Tags: cmd

My script:

```
PATH
echo done
pause
```

The output (missing initial blank line consumed by this forum):

```
S:\TLIB admin\Sets' extra tracks finder>PATH
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\EaseUS\Todo Backup\bin\

S:\TLIB admin\Sets' extra tracks finder>echo done
done

S:\TLIB admin\Sets' extra tracks finder>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: echo creates a blank line (in DOS).

Comment: By default DOS adds a new line (or blank line). So, what do you want - you want to have no additional line every time you echo? For what purpose?

Comment: @Mukus, the issue is not specific to echo. I'll change my question to use anotehr command too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@` prefix to stop the command from displaying itself also like this:

```
@echo hello 
@echo there
@pause
```

or you can also turn echo off first like this:

```
@echo off
echo hello
echo there
pause
```

Comment: You're right - I didn't answer 'why'. Microsoft decided to put a blank line after it executed a command so that there is a visible separator between each command for readability when echo is 'on' since it is outputting both the command and the results of the command. You can stop this by turning echo 'off' in one of the two ways I showed.

Comment: "Microsoft decided to put a blank line after it executed a command so that there is a visible separator between each command for readability when echo is 'on' since it is outputting both the command and the results of the command." Note that the separator is not between the command and the results of the command. It is between the results of the command and the next prompt. "You can stop this by turning echo 'off' in one of the two ways I showed." That doesn't stop just the blank line, note.